# How static methods runs concurrently or parallely in multithread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have read that, static methods are stored in class area of JVM. so we have only one copy of static methods. can any one explain how static methods run parallely for multiple request(using multithread) in java.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "static methods are stored"? Which aspect of the methods? What would you expect to be stored for an instance method compared with a static method?

Comment: You only have "one copy" of non-static methods too. You don't need to duplicate method code for reasons of concurrency.

Comment: @kayaman. non static methods are duplicated for each object created right

Comment: @vijayakumar Not sure what you have read; but either you should read more carefully; or you should select more carefully what you are reading.

Comment: @vijayakumar: *"non static methods are duplicated for each object created right"* No, they aren't; there's no reason for them to be, they have no instance-specific information in them. Instance **data** is duplicated per object, not instance methods.

Comment: can i know the reason for downvoting.so that i can rectify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing really to explain. Static methods (or indeed instance methods) are *code*. Threads are used to execute code. Where the code is stored has nothing to do with threading; you can use multiple threads to execute the same code.

Think of it like a recipe on a piece of paper. If you have the recipe up on a corkboard where two people can see it, then both people can follow the recipe at the same time. The code is the recipe; the corkboard is the part of the computer's memory where the code is loaded; the people are the threads.

Re [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211880/how-static-methods-runs-concurrently-or-parallely-in-multithread-in-java/29211938#comment46633363_29211880):

> non static methods are duplicated for each object created right

No, they aren't; there's no reason for them to be, they have no instance-specific information in them. Instance **data** is stored separately per object, but not instance methods.

In essence and glossing over a lot of details, an instance method is just a static method, but before calling the instance method the JVM sets up `this` to refer to the object that the method is being called on, so that you can use `this` (explicitly or implicitly) to interact with the object's instance data. `this` is effectively just an invisible argument to the method. Again, that's glossing over a lot of details, but it's enough for a basic understanding.

Comment: can u pls suggest a link that, what are the things will happen when we create a object. I can't find exact answer through google.

Comment: @vijayakumar: Any good book on Java will go into it. For instance, *Head First Java* by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates; I believe it's currently in its second edition. That example is slightly dated, only covering up through Java 5 (and important things have happened in Java since then), but it's still a good book for getting started.